# How to store dispatch_queue_t in nsarray

Tags: nsarray, grand-central-dispatch

Here I have a bunch of dispatch_queue_t, and I want to organize them with a NSArray. But as far as I know, there's no such API to do so. So how can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSArray` is not mutable. You must use `NSMutableArray`, that is subclass of `NSArray`, to add objects.

And, from iOS 6.0 SDK and the Mac OS X 10.8 SDK, Dispatch Queue is declared as Objective-C types. Thus you can use Dispatch Queue object as Objective-C object.

```
@import Foundation;

int main()
{
    NSMutableArray *array = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    dispatch_queue_t q = dispatch_get_global_queue(0, 0);
    NSLog(@"       q=%@", q);

    [array addObject:q];

    NSLog(@"array[0]=%@", array[0]);

    return 0;
}
```

Result:

```
       q=<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.default-qos[0x7fff79749b40]>
array[0]=<OS_dispatch_queue_root: com.apple.root.default-qos[0x7fff79749b40]>
```

Comment: Thx, NSMutableArray is what I mean, sorry for the mistake. And this is what I need.